# How to generate Synthesis model for two template paths

Tags: synthesis

I am using Synthesis ORM for Sitecore for auto generation.
Purpose is to generate model for two template paths.

I have given below settings in `Synthesis.Local.config` based on `<TemplatePathRoot>/sitecore/templates</TemplatePathRoot>` pattern

and paths like

```
<includedPaths hint="list:AddTemplatePath">
  <templates>/sitecore/templates/path1</templates>
  <templates>/sitecore/templates/path2</templates>
</includedPaths>
```

But it always generates model for template at second position. Can you please suggest if above syntax is correct and how can I generate model for both paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify different names for those paths. The second one is "overwriting" the definition of first one.

So instead of:

```
<includedPaths hint="list:AddTemplatePath">
  <templates>/sitecore/templates/path1</templates>
  <templates>/sitecore/templates/path2</templates>
</includedPaths>
```

you should use this for example:

```
<includedPaths hint="list:AddTemplatePath">
  <templates>/sitecore/templates/path1</templates>
  <commonTemplates>/sitecore/templates/path2</commonTemplates>
</includedPaths>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The "Sitecore way" is actually hinted in the snippet itself.

```<templates hint="base templates">.../.../etc</templates>
<templates hint="feature templates">.../.../etc</templates>
```

and so on.